Question on concurrent normals in a Parabola
Normals drawn at points A, B and C of a parabola are concurrent at $N (4,2)$. If $A \equiv (3,3)$ and $B \equiv (1,-1)$. Then which of the following can be true?
I) Focus is at S $\displaystyle\equiv \Big( \frac{6}{5}, \frac{-3}{5}\Big)$
II) Slope of directrix is $\frac{-1}{2}$
III) Number of parabolas possible is 1
IV) Number of parabolas possible is 2
My Attempt:
We know that,
Normal through A is $(y-2) = (-1)(x-4)$, ie. Normal through A: $x+y = 6$
Normal through B is $(y-2) = (1)(x-4)$, ie. Normal through B: $x-y = 2$
These are 2 perpendicular normals(or hence tangents), which tells us that A and B are the extremities of a focal chord.
Equation of AB is $(y-3) = 2(x-3)$, ie. AB is y + 3 = 2x
And we know that focus will lie on AB. Let's assume it to be $(h,2h-3)$
Tangent through A is : $y=x+6$
Tangent through B is : $x+y=0$
Their point of intersection is (-3,3)
We know that Image of Focus lies on tangent lies on the directrix, which I have shown in the rough sketch.
I am stuck after this


Normal lines $AN$ and $BN$ are perpendicular between them. Hence the tangent lines through $A$ and $B$ are also perpendicular and meet at the origin $O=(0,0)$ ($ANBO$ is a rectangle).
But perpendicular tangents of a parabola meet on the directrix, hence $O$ lies on the directrix. Moreover, if $M=(2,1)$ is the midpoint of $AB$, then line $OM$ is parallel to the axis of the parabola and perpendicular to the directrix. Hence the directrix is the line of equation $y=-2x$ (orange in the figure).
Focus $F$, finally, is the projection of $O$ on line $AB$. In fact, if $H$ and $K$ are the projections of $A$ and $B$ on the directrix,
point $F$ is both the reflection of $K$ about $OB$ and the reflection of $H$ about $OA$, hence $AF=AH$ and $BF=BK$. A simple computation gives $F=(6/5,-3/5)$.
Note that the existence of a third normal through $N$ is not relevant for the solution.


Thanks a lot for the solution, but can you please clarify how did you said that "line OM is parallel to the axis of the parabola"

@TanishAgarwal This is known as Archimedes' Lemma, see here: https://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Geometry/ArchimedesTriangle.shtml

Understood, thanks for the answer.
